# .htaccess Forward all mail subdomains to /webmail/

Tags: htaccess, subdomain, directory

I would like to write a .htaccess rewrite command that takes any url with a subdomain mail and forwards them to whatever domain included that subdomain with /webmail at the end.

e.g.

mail.zane.com would forward to zane.com/webmail
mail.prowebmasters.com would forward to prowebmasters.com/webmail.

In short, I have a master domain with my host with addon domains in folders on the master domain.  Any time I type mail.site.com it is forwarding to the index.html of the master site.  Instead of doing that I want the sites to open /webmail/ of the site.

Answer (score 1):

This will work but you'll have to copy the rewrite into each domains `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webmail/
RewriteRule (.*) /webmail/$1
```

Comment: A few mods, you could make domain.com unecessary in line 1: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail\..+$ [NC]` and for line3 the 301 and last flag: `RewriteRule (.*) /mail/$1 [R=301,L]`